# Aligning a link with the width of the table

Tags: html, css

I've searched enough on this topic and finally arrived here.
This is my code:

```
echo "<a href='sresult.php?pid=$pi&pname=$p&dep=$d'><table style='background-color: $colour; table-layout: fixed;'>"; ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $arr['pid']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $arr['pname']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $arr['year']; ?></td>
                </tr>
        </table></a>
```

This is just a part of my actual code. And the css:

```
table {
            border: 2px solid black;
            border-radius: 10px;
            position: relative;
            top: 5px;
            left: 400px;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 60%;
        }

        td
        {
            text-align: center;
            margin: auto;
            font-size: large;
            color: whitesmoke;
            padding: 0 150px 0 150px;
        }
```

[image: Webpage showing the problem]

Now in the above image you can see the width of the table i.e the colored blocks. But since it is wrapped by anchor tag, the link extends from extreme left to extreme right of the browser. I want only the colored block to be the link and not the whole stripe. Any help would be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/53Ssk/embedded/result/

Above is a jsfiddle of the modified code.

Comment: jsfiddle will, usually, help us, help you faster.

Comment: The code contains php. Hence I din go for jsfiddle.. But i'll modify and upload since you said

Comment: remove position:relative and understand that with or without it, table uses exactly the same space and spot on the screen. <a> has no strange behavior at all, it wraps space used by table. relative + coordonate only moves it for your eyes :)  http://jsfiddle.net/53Ssk/1/

Comment: @j08691 in HTML5 context , <a> wrapping a block element is valid. it can hold either flow or phrasing content.

Comment: @GCyrillus - Actually that wasn't what I was referring to. I missed the opening table tag and only saw an anchor around a tr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not too sure of final result expected,

but if it is to center a link you should reset `display` on `<a>` and use `margin:auto;`

**Notice:** this structure is valid with `HTML5` doctype document, use it in your real page to validate it.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/53Ssk/2/)**

---

Your CSS becomes :

```
a {
    width: 60%;
    margin:auto;
    display:block;
}
table {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red; 
    table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: large;
    color: whitesmoke;      
}
```

---

HTML used :

```
<a href="#">
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td>hey</td>
       <td>wassup</td>
       <td>people</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
</a>
```

Comment: @GCyrillius Fabulous!! It's working.. The only thing i forgot was the child node concept. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You cant do your markup that way. It is not valid. So to acheve the result you need to change some structure

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="same-href">Hey</a></td>
            <td><a href="same-href">wassup</a></td>
            <td><a href="same-href">people</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table a {display:block;}
```

You can put 3 links but set the same link to it

Comment: actually in html5 you are now allowed to put a table inside an anchor - http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2F53Ssk%2Fshow%2Flight%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Also this is less efficient for actually what i wanted